# Is there a C++ fmt library format equivalent to the Fortran scale factor (P) edit descriptor for writing formatted output?

Tags: c++, fmt

For writing formatted output, Fortran has the P edit descriptor that will scale the result by factor(s) of 10.  For example:

```
Program Test
Real a;
a = 123.456
write(6, "(3p, f12.2)") a;
End Program Test
```

Returns:

```
   123456.00
```

I am looking into ways to write an equivalent C++ formatted write statement using the fmt library. In actuality, I am writing a script to replace several thousand of these Fortran statements with C++ equivalents. The current method I'm considering (shown below) of multiplying the variable by the appropriate power of 10 will make life complicated because of how the code I'm parsing is set up.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY
#include "fmt/format.h"
#include "fmt/ostream.h"

int main()
{
    float a = 123.456;
    std::ofstream newfile ("newfile.txt");
    fmt::print(newfile, "{:12.2f}", pow(10, 3) * a);
}
```

It would be very convenient for my script if there was an easy way to scale the values inside the format definition, i.e., within the second argument, "{:12.2f}", of the fmt::print statement. So far though, all I've come up with is the shown method of multiplying the relevant variable by the appropriate power of 10 and then using that value.

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"will make life complicated because of how the code I'm parsing is set up"*? I think this is the best solution, except that I wouldn't trust `pow` to be constexpr, and would use `1e3` instead.

Comment: A lot of the formats are defined as strings, such as "format_x = 'some format'", then used in multiple write statements elsewhere: "write(file, format_x) a, b, c;"  If there's no C++ "p" equivalent, then I can't simply modify the predefined formats, I'd have to extract the scale factor position and value in each predefined format statement, and write it into each write statement for the corresponding variable.  Not the end of the world, but just will take more time to implement.

Comment: I guess you could add a new [presentation_type](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/db745986f264cc8f36c2d56bff7f6a2fbcfcc591/include/fmt/core.h#L2045)